# socket.io server not responding on Windows server

Tags: node.js, windows, socket.io

I have a socket.io server running on NodeJS. My server is a Windows server 2019 standard. Socket.io is listening on port 3000 but all pings and client (phone) connections time out. No error is captured on socket.io side with event connect_error listener. I opened port 3000 in Windows firewall. Relevant code for my socket.io is this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');


const { createServer } = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const httpServer = createServer();
const io = new Server(httpServer, { allowEIO3: true, rejectUnauthorized: false });
...


 socket.on("connect_error", (error) => {
        console.log("Connection error: {$error.message}");
    });

httpServer.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

It all works fine if client and server are on the same machine (so when localhosting). All I see on client side is an xhr poll error.